# CentOS and Samba logs

Tags: centos, samba

I've noticed that Samba server logs to `/var/log/smb.conf` and `/var/log/messages`. How to disable logs from `/var/log/messages`? I've tried to edit the rsyslog config file:

*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;**smb.none**              /var/log/messages

- but this disabled all messages in /var/log/messages

System: CentOS 6.2
Samba Version 3.5.10-116.el6_2

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default logging for samba on CentOS is to log to `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` and out of the box the `log file` setting is `/var/log/samba/%m` (the connecting machine log) so it looks like someone has made changes to at least some of the defaults.

The smb.conf `syslog` directive says this

> This parameter maps how Samba debug messages are logged onto the system syslog logging levels. Samba debug level zero maps onto syslog LOG_ERR, debug level one maps onto LOG_WARNING, debug level two maps onto LOG_NOTICE, debug level three maps onto LOG_INFO.
>   All higher levels are mapped to LOG_DEBUG.
>
> This parameter sets the threshold for sending messages to syslog. Only messages 
>       with debug level less than this value will be sent to syslog. There still will be 
>       some logging to log.[sn]mbd even if syslog only is enabled.
>
> Default: syslog = 1

This means that under default conditions LOG_ERR messages will be logged to syslog too. You gould put

```
syslog = 0
```

in your `/etc/smb.conf` which should stop anything going to syslog.

You'll need to check you .etc/samba/smb.conf file for

It would probably be a good idea to check through the [smb.conf documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) too for other logging options.